# Getting ClassNotFoundException on com.ibm.ws.security.jaspi.ProviderRegistry on Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, websphere, java-security

I am using Spring Boot application with tomcat as a container.

on some machine it is working, and on other mochine im getting:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: AuthConfigFactory error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.ws.security.jaspi.ProviderRegistry
        at javax.security.auth.message.config.AuthConfigFactory.getFactory(AuthConfigFactory.java:85) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar!/:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.findJaspicProvider(AuthenticatorBase.java:1205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar!/:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.getJaspicProvider(AuthenticatorBase.java:1195) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar!/:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:469) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar!/:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar!/:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar!/:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar!/:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar!/:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar!/:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar!/:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar!/:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1457) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar!/:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar!/:8.5.20]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1176) [na:1.7.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) [na:1.7.0]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar!/:8.5.20]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:795) [na:1.7.0]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.ws.security.jaspi.ProviderRegistry
        at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186) ~[na:1.7.0]
        at javax.security.auth.message.config.AuthConfigFactory$1.run(AuthConfigFactory.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar!/:8.5.20]
        at javax.security.auth.message.config.AuthConfigFactory$1.run(AuthConfigFactory.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar!/:8.5.20]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:330) ~[na:1.7.0]
        at javax.security.auth.message.config.AuthConfigFactory.getFactory(AuthConfigFactory.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar!/:8.5.20]
        ... 16 common frames omitted
```

The class `com.ibm.ws.security.jaspi.ProviderRegistry` look like a WebSphere class, and it is not related to my application as I am using tomcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that java security trying to create AuthConfigFactory in `AuthConfigFactory::getFactory()`.
It first check if the security property `authconfigprovider.factory` exist.

If the property `authconfigprovider.factory` not exist, it will create as default instance of the class `org.apache.catalina.authenticator.jaspic.AuthConfigFactoryImpl`, that it will be probably ok.

The issue is when you are trying to run on machine that have defined that security property `authconfigprovider.factory` as `com.ibm.ws.security.jaspi.ProviderRegistry` in java.security file (might be that machine is used for WebSphere).

So of course you dont have the class `com.ibm.ws.security.jaspi.ProviderRegistry` and you will get `ClassNotFoundException`.

To solve it, try to create your own java.security file and locate it under your application, inside that file - override the property like `authconfigprovider.factory=org.apache.catalina.authenticator.jaspic.AuthConfigFactoryImpl`.

And to make your new java.security file active, add the jvm argument `-Djava.security.properties=java.security`.